# Код выполняется асинхронно

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Есть кусок кода:

```js
let news = [];

docs_id.forEach(async el => {
  const news_ = await News.find({ _id: el._id });
  news.push(news_);
  console.log(news.length)
});

console.log(news.length)

console.log('---------------');
```

Здесь переменная docs_id равна массиву подобного вида:

```js
[
  { _id: 5ff470ba061b231930bc4717 },
  { _id: 5ff470d0061b231930bc4718 }
]
```

Почему-то при выполнении кода в консоль выводится:

```js
0
---------------
1
2
```

То-есть `.forEach` выполняется асинхронно.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А что надо чтобы было? Замените forEach  на обычный for

Comment: вчера же был [абсолютно аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1227600)...

Comment: @nörbörnën, просмотрел..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас `forEach` просто выполняет асинхронную функцию, которая даст результат только через некоторое время. Но два следующих `console.log'a` выполнятся сразу. [Пример очень похож на Ваш](https://itnext.io/why-async-await-in-a-foreach-is-not-working-5f13118f90d).

```
(async() => {
  let news = [];
  for (const el of docs_id) {
    const news_ = await News.find({
      _id: el._id
    });
    news.push(news_);
    console.log(news.length);
  }

  console.log(news.length);
  console.log('---------------');
})();
```